# Laravel MySQL pivot table to column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I use Laravel and pivot table with MySQL.

I have a dynamic number of rows on my `table A` and I want to turn them into columns.

For example

```
   +-----------+  +-----------+  +----------------------+
   |  table A  |  |  table B  |  | table C(pivot table) |  
   +-----------+  +-----------+  +----+--------+--------+
   |   str1    |  |    1      |  | 1  |  str1  | value1 |
   |   str2    |  |    2      |  | 2  |  str1  | value2 |
   |   str3    |  |    3      |  | 1  |  str2  | value3 |
   +-----------+  +-----------+  | 2  |  str2  | value4 |
                                 | 3  |  str2  | value5 |
                                 | 2  |  str3  | value6 |
                                 | 3  |  str3  | value7 |
                                 +----+--------+--------+
```

What I tried to achieve is to get an array of every rows on `table B (order by id)` and for each rows on `table A`, to have the value.

So every rows on `table A` become a columns on my final request with value inside. If there's no record, value is set to null.

Is it possible ?

Comment: please show the code of what you have tried or at least an attempt.

Comment: I tried several sql but nothing works, I don't know how to do with pivot table

Comment: check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many